# How to add some custom icon on my google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have shown **Google Map V2** in my Android App. Now I want to get the icon like following image has shown, Which is below of Current Location icon of the map.

[image: This is image of map, which i want to do the same as shown here]

I am not getting any idea that how to do this. I will appreciate if someone guide me through this functionality.

Comment: post your code here..you can add icon using marker option

Comment: no, i don't want to add marker, I want to show the icons like list and pen are displaying on the map on the left hand side.

Comment: then you have make an xml file on which add map and also this icon

Comment: Use addContentView() for adding another icon

Comment: but i think easy option is directly put icon from xml fiel which contain map fragement

Comment: how to do this. guide me ,

Comment: @yuvaツ  How can i use addContentView, tell me in detail.

Comment: @GulnazGhanchi I have posted answer try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Replace your mapfragmnt xml to this 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I got somewhat, what i wanted by this answer. Thank You. I was just confused that how to achieve it, i thought there must be some unique technique.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button icon=new Button(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT;
getActivity().addContentView(icon,params);
```

Comment: plz provide op what is your_icon>> explain in detil so he/she can understand

Comment: hmmm also app get crashed when run this code ... cause of no parent layout presend so class cast exception occured plese check twice and then provide solution

Comment: @DigveshPatel-I have used it in my application. And its working well.Of course this will be used in activity having parent layout as he/she is using map.

Comment: @DigveshPatel You should try it first and then send your opinion